SIGSEGV on close Application in ACE 7.1.2 TAO 3.1.2
The debugger shows that when the client application terminates, TAO_Resource_Factory::~TAO_Resource_Factory() is called before TAO_Thread_Lane_Resources::shutdown_reactor() is called, in the code of which this->orb_core_.resource_factory() is called, which leads to a SIGSEGW.How to solve this problem?

I wrote release of resources in atexit function and issue was resolved.
